# How would I change the code to show the entire kick animation?

Tags: javascript, game-development, p5.js

I'm working on this project which is based on the p5.js framework where we have to design a game. I have a separate animation for punch and kick, and the punches are working just fine. The issue is with the kick animation, in that it only shows the first frame of it. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you!

```
var isFacingLeft = false; // set initial value to false
var punching = false; // set initial value to false
var kicking = false;

function controls() {
  // check if x key is pressed
  if (keyDown("x")) {
    // set velocity to 0
    goku.velocityX = 0;
    // display left or right punch animation based on which direction the player is facing
    if (isFacingLeft) {
      goku.setAnimation("goku_punch_left");
    } else {
      goku.setAnimation("goku_punch_right");
    }
    punching = true; // player is punching
  }
  // check if z key is pressed
  else if (keyDown("z")) {
    // set velocity to 0
    goku.velocityX = 0;
    // display left or right kick animation based on which direction the player is facing
    if (isFacingLeft) {
      goku.setAnimation("goku_kick_left");
    } else {
      goku.setAnimation("goku_kick_right");
    }
    kicking = true; // player is kicking
  } else if (goku.velocityX !== 0) { // check if player is running
    goku.setAnimation(isFacingLeft ? "goku_run_left" : "goku_run_right");
  } else {
    punching = false; // player is not punching
    kicking = false; // player is not kicking
    goku.setAnimation("goku_copy");
  }

  // reset animation to idle if punch or kick animation is finished
  if (goku.getAnimationLabel() === "goku_punch_left" || goku.getAnimationLabel() === "goku_punch_right" || goku.getAnimationLabel() === "goku_kick_left" || goku.getAnimationLabel() === "goku_kick_right") {
    if (goku.animation.getFrame() === goku.getAnimationLabel().length - 1) {
      goku.setAnimation("goku_copy");
    }
  }
}
```

It was meant to show a kick animation regardless of whether the player is running, facing left or right, etc.